# Does Django Automatically Sanitise urls for directory traversal attacks?

Tags: django, directory-traversal

I have a view in my Django web app like this :

```
def download_func(request, url):
    file_url = '/home/mylaptop/myproject/' + url
    file = open (file_url, "rb").read()
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="application/octect-
stream")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = %s' %url
    return response
```

and a url conf like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^media/videos/(?P<url>[-._\w]+)/$', views.download_func),
...
]
```

Downloading a video that is uploaded before is perfectly working, but my question is:  "Is there the risk of directory traversal attack in my app?"

if "yes" how can I fix it (or is there a better way of writting view for downloading while development?)

I have been testing directory traversal on it and understood that Django automatically sanitises urls containing "../../" is that right?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Django to stream media files in this way, instead of using your web server to do it?

Comment: The best way to send files is via your web server, without it hitting python code. If you have to use Python to set a header or do permissions, then you should use X-Accel in nginx and x-sendfile in Apache. Those will let you tweak the request and still have the server send the file. Doing it like this moves the file into memory!